# Java - Why I can't enumerate certificates in a KeyStore by using their alias?

Tags: java, keystore, pkcs#12

```
KeyStore keystore_client = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");

try(InputStream keyInput = new FileInputStream("2.pfx")){
  keystore_client.load(keyInput, null);
}
Enumeration<String> e = keystore_client.aliases();
while(e.hasMoreElements()){
  String alias = e.nextElement();
  if(keystore_client.getCertificate(alias)==null)
    throw new RuntimeException("Cannot get Certificate");
}
```

When I run this code, I always get the exception: **"Cannot get Certificate"**.

How can I extract certificates from a pkcs12 file?

Edit:
The pfx file was created by openssl.

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out 2.pfx -in server.crt -inkey server.key  
$ keytool  -list -keystore 2.pfx  
Enter keystore password:  

*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************  
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *  
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *  
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *  
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************  

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

1, May 9, 2016, PrivateKeyEntry,
```

Comment: Hi @Tom, keystore_client.getCertificate(alias) returns null.

Comment: Have you checked which alias causes that trouble? And this may also mean, that the alias exists, but there is no certificate assigned to it (any more).

Comment: Hi @Tom, Thanks for your help. I just added the information about the pfx file. Please take a look. And the alias is "1" .

Comment: You always get *what* exception?

Comment: Hi @EJP ,sorry, edited.

Comment: A quoted string isn't an exception. Provide the exception. The whole thing. Class, message, stack trace.

Comment: @EJP A stacktrace won't help much when OPs throws that exception himself. It wouldn't contain any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are not getting the certificate is because you are not providing a password. Take a closer look at the warning you are getting:

```
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************  
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *  
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *  
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *  
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
```

If you do JUnit tests on your code and try keystores with a password and without a password you will see that only the ones that need password will let you get certificates via this code, and of course provided that you input a correct password.

Another thing you'll see if you try to extract this from the command line is:

```
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************
* The integrity of the information stored in your keystore  *
* has NOT been verified!  In order to verify its integrity, *
* you must provide your keystore password.                  *
*****************  WARNING WARNING WARNING  *****************

keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <1> has no certificate
```

Comment: The pfx file doesn't have a password. So must I add a password for it?

Comment: If you do not put it, it will not be able to verify the request. Try to add a password to it and see what happens. If you use the command like to extract the certificate you will see that you'll get "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <1> has no certificate
". Try this command line "keytool -keystore 2.pfx -storetype pkcs12 -exportcert -alias 1 -file server.crt"